# Manaul SQL cluster failover on 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql, cluster

I need to do a restart of the clustered SQL instance to fix a problem with tempDB and i am not sure of the easiest way to do this. We have just upgraded our servers to Windows 2008R2 running SQL 2008R2.  The main cluster is a 2 node cluster running active/passive.

As this is just to fix tempDB, my current plan is to just move the clustered SQL instance to the passive node and fail it back again, is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already noted failing over to the secondary then failing back to the primary when you're done is the easiest way. Whenever we have to perform work on a clustered instance over here the above mentioned is the way we do it. It's the quickest way

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation - haven't done this before and wanted to check first